# sugarcrm custom module select all across multiple page

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I created  print the address in list view of custom leads  the list view code is as given below.

There are 25 records totally first i select 20 records(select this page) ,its performing the action for 20 records which is correct if i seelct all its performing action for only 20 records ,so its not selecting the 25 records ...

```
protected function buildMyMenuItem()
    {
        global $app_strings;

        return <<<EOHTML
<a class="menuItem"  style="width: 150px;" href="#" onmouseover='hiliteItem(this,"yes");' 
        onmouseout='unhiliteItem(this);' 
        onclick="sugarListView.get_checks();
        if(sugarListView.get_checks_count() < 1) {
            alert('{$app_strings['LBL_LISTVIEW_NO_SELECTED']}');
            return false;
        }
        document.MassUpdate.action.value='print';
        document.MassUpdate.submit();">Print Label</a>
EOHTML;
    }
```

Im calling it in the controller class  below is the code

```
class CustomLeadsController extends SugarController
{
    public function action_print() {
        if ( !empty($_REQUEST['uid']) ) {
            $recordIds = explode(',',$_REQUEST['uid']);   
            print_r($recordIds);
           ?>

      <form>
        <div align="right">
          <input name="button" type="button" onclick="window.print()" value="print" />
        </div>
      </form>
      <table width="1024px" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">  
  <?php

      $i = 0;
      foreach ($recordIds as $recordId )
      {

           $bean = SugarModule::get($_REQUEST['module'])->loadBean();
          // print_r($bean);
                $bean->retrieve($recordId);
          if ($i % 4 == 0)
          {
              echo '<tr>';
          }
  ?>
  <td align="left" width="25%" height="100px" STYLE="font-family: 'comic sans ms', fantasy; padding:10px; font-size:12px;">
   <?php echo $bean->get_summary_text(); ?>
   <br>

    <?php echo nl2br($bean->primary_address_street); ?>

      <?php 
      if($bean->primary_address_city != "")
      {
       echo "<br>";
      echo nl2br($bean->primary_address_city); 
      }
      ?>
       <br>
      <?php echo nl2br($bean->primary_address_state); ?>
       <br>   
      <?php echo nl2br($bean->primary_address_postalcode); ?>

  </td>
  <?php        
          if ($i % 4 == 3)
          {
              echo '</tr>';
          }
          $i++; 
      }

      //here is a check in case you don't have multiple of 3 rows
      if ($i % 4 != 0)
      {
          echo '</tr>';
      }

  ?>
</table>        

<?php
        }

        sugar_die('');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue a while ago, `$_REQUEST['uid']` only shows items selected on the page, not the full filtered list.

Check if the entire list has been selected, `$_REQUEST['select_entire_list'] == 1`

Get the query that that has created the filtered list - `$_REQUEST['current_query_by_page']`

You can then use the Mass Update class to get a list of all the selected records

```
$mass = new MassUpdate();
$mass->setSugarBean($bean);    
$mass->generateSearchWhere($module, $_REQUEST['current_query_by_page']);
$seed = BeanFactory::getBean($module);
$query = $seed->create_new_list_query('name ASC', $mass->where_clauses);
$result = $db->query($query, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could use a script function  for getting all the selected check-boxes from all pages of the records as  follows :

```
sugarListView.get_checks();
var v = document.MassUpdate.uid.value;
alert("V : "+v);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the $_SESSION global in PHP if you don't want to use the bean. This can be particularly useful to change a large number of records quickly. You need to change the module name in the ['Module2_Query'] index.

This returns the full query for whatever search was entered in the filter. At that point you just use the global $db to get the values you need.

```
if($_REQUEST['select_entire_list'] == 1) {
        $searchQuery = $_SESSION['Leads2_QUERY'];
}
```