# How to get selected options' ids in multiple pages in SugarCRM?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM 6.5.x CE version. Currently I am trying to get the ids of all selected records in listview in "Calls" module in CRM across multiple pages.

Suppose if I have 100 records and if I select only 50 out of them, then I should get ids of all selected 50 records.

I am referring this link to achieve the same:
[sugarcrm custom module select all across multiple page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971086/sugarcrm-custom-module-select-all-across-multiple-page)

This is the code I am using:

```
$mass = new MassUpdate();
$mass->setSugarBean($bean);    
$mass->generateSearchWhere('Calls', $_REQUEST['current_query_by_page']);
$seed = BeanFactory::getBean('Calls');
$query = $seed->create_new_list_query('name ASC', $mass->where_clauses);
$result = $db->query($query, true);
```

But the `$query` I am getting in above code and as mentioned in above link, it is for getting ids of all records in listview irrespective of its selection or not.

I just want to get the ids of only selected records. So whether it is only 1 or 99 out of 100. Kindly guide me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer of this. Kindly find the below code:

```
sugarListView.get_checks();  
var selected_ids = document.MassUpdate.uid.value;
```

Add this in view.list.php file of any module and it will give you ids of selected records.

I found this answer on [SugarCRM Community Forum](https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/28644-how-to-get-selected-options-ids-in-multiple-pages-in-sugarcrm). Thank you all.